# Bootloader fails to install Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bootloader

Install gets to almost completion, then pop up appears saying bootloader failed to install.  It gives me 3 choices, pick another partition, continue without and manually load, or quit install.  All options fail and everything crashes.

Computer was a Windows 8 from the factory.  Finally got fed up and wiped it, now trying to start fresh with Ubuntu but I can't seem to get any version to work.  I also tried Ubuntu 14.04 and bootloader fails to install in the same way.

Comment: How are installing, namely with what partition scheme, is the question here. If you let the installer do the partitioning it'll work. Manually - and considering that you're installing in UEFI mode (as you should) - you must not forget to create a small FAT32 partition (300MB should be enough for everything, including multiboot) as the ESP (EFI System Partition).

Answer (score 0):

Unplug all drives and peripheral devices except boot/root drive.  Install should complete fine.  Once you verify installation, you can plug other devices.